# Couldn't find ANT in the Cygwin repositiories. Why's that?

Tags: cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing ANT on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858732/installing-ant-on-cygwin)

I've just installed Cygwin and managed to get all the required stuff up and running but I couldn't figure out why ANT wasn't listed in the Cygwin repos. Could someone tell me why, please?

MAKE was, ANT wasn't. I might be missing something here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858732/installing-ant-on-cygwin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ant is a java program and is not unix specific and so does not need cygwin to run. Install directly from [apache ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

You can modify ant.bat for use under Windows directly or the shell script ant for use under cygwin